# Copy file to protected directory using AppleScript

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, bash, zsh

[image]

I'm trying to simulate Finder's file copy, but to a protected directory, using AppleScript.  The goal is to copy a single file but elevate when needed, like Finder will behave when doing it manually.

- Initially I tried to use `do shell script [...] with administrator privileges`

  - This didn't work, I believe due to sandboxing, `osascript` the shell commands could read from my Desktop directory when run as me, but were blocked when run as administrator.
- I tried to use the `copy` command, but quickly found that it's [NOT for copying files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW53).  This is confusing, [many solutions are still using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909266/3196753).
- I'm reading that [`duplicate` is likely the keyword I should be focusing on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28791183/3196753) but I'm struggling with using `POSIX file` and when using `alias`.

An example of a test without elevation:

```
set posixSrc to (POSIX file "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test.txt") as alias
set posixDst to (POSIX file "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test2.txt") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate posixSrc to posixDst
end tell
```

An example of a test with elevation:

```
set posixSrc to (POSIX file "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test.txt") as alias
set posixDst to (POSIX file "/Applications/My Special App.app") as alias

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate posixSrc to posixDst
end tell
```

Unfortunately, between POSIX and alias, I'm struggling to figure it all out.  Some errors I receive:

```
error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10010

error "Can’t make \"/Users/darwin/Desktop/test2.txt\" into type alias." number -1700 from "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test2.txt" to alias

error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000 from file (file "Macintosh HD:Users:darwin:Desktop:test.txt")

error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712
```

I'm currently testing these with **Script Editor** but a solution in Terminal is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

```
tell application "Finder"
    set posixSource to (POSIX file "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test.txt" as alias)
    set posixDest to (POSIX file "/Applications/My Special App.app/Contents/" as alias)
    duplicate file posixSource to folder posixDest with replacing
end tell
```

... and the one-liner:

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate file (POSIX file "/Users/darwin/Desktop/test.txt" as alias) to folder (POSIX file "/Applications/My Special App.app/Contents/" as alias) with replacing
```

Some important distinctions from failed attempts:

- You can't alias a file which doesn't yet exist.  For destination, use the destination's parent folder instead.
- You can't copy into the root of an Application bundle (e.g. `My Special App.app`).  You must copy into the `My Special App.app/Contents` instead.
- Pay special attention to the keywords `file` and `folder` as they're provided to the `duplicate` command.
- When a problem occurs, it can deadlock **Script Editor**.  Wrap your `duplicate` call in `ignoring application responses` [...] `end ignoring` to speed up testing which results in timeouts.
- When converting to a one-liner you'll need to use the keyword `to` after the application name.

Comment: Was just typing a comment to raise your second and third points when I got an alert telling me that an answer has been posted. The first point is generally true but the specifics matter — it's not always consistent.

Comment: @Mockman thanks, removed the part about variable scope.  False-positive when testing, good catch.